# Logstash parse fail when using Time.parse under ruby fiter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Logstash version 6.4.2
Here is the code:

```
filter{
    if [@metadata][isDropMode] == "true" {

        if [@metadata][mode] == "a" {

            date{
                match => ["time", "yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss","yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
                timezone => "%{timeZone}"
                target => "time"
            }
        }

        if [@metadata][mode] == "b" {

            mutate { add_field => { "time" => "%{bTime}" } }
        }

        ruby {  
            init => "require 'time'" 

            code => 
                "   
                    t1 = Time.now.utc
                    t2 = event.get('time').to_s
                    event.set('timeDistance', (t1 - Time.parse(t2)).to_s)

                    timeDistance = event.get ('timeDistance')

                    if (timeDistance.to_f > 30.0) 

                        event.set('[@metadata][drop]', 'true')

                    end
                "
            }   
    }
}
```

Generation of _rubyexception are inconsistent under some run cycles this code fails ,While under other run cycles code works just fine.
event data are the same under each cycle.

the problematic line is: `Time.parse`

Any idea why `Time.parse` is just unpredictable? why each cycle is all events gets _rubyexception  and other run cycles run just fine?

maybe other solution to just get time difference  in seconds ?

thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the `bTime` field contains a valid date?

Comment: yes it's fully valid.  bTime is a filed that is being generated by another filter as date {....target => "bTime"}, in addition i print logs and I can see that It's a valid date.

Comment: Add some exception handling to your code to see what error is being produced.  http://svops.com/blog/handling-exceptions-in-the-ruby-filter/